# How to add another path and prefix couple to the components/dirs option in nuxt.config.js?

Tags: configuration, nuxt.js

In `nuxt.config.js`, how to add another `path`/`prefix` couple ?

```
components: {
  dirs: [
    '~/components',
    {
      path: '~/components/profile/',
      prefix: 'Profile'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding another object into the array:

```js
components: {
  dirs: [
    '~/components',
    {
      path: '~/components/profile/',
      prefix: 'Profile'
    },
    {
      path: '~/components/other-path/',
      prefix: 'Other Prefix'
    }
  ]
}
```